# Cannot perform https request in ssr

Tags: node.js, angular, https, angular-universal

I'm running a very annoying error with https calls from server.
The error is `Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error`.

In my angular application I perform an https call, when it's executed on the browser everything is fine, but when this call it's executed on the server I get the error.
This is the complete error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {
headers: HttpHeaders { normalizedNames: Map {}, lazyUpdate: null, 
headers: Map {} },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: null,
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error',
  error:
   ProgressEvent {
     type: 'error',
     target:
      XMLHttpRequest {
        onloadstart: null,
        onprogress: null,
        onabort: null,
        onerror: null,
        onload: null,
        ontimeout: null,
        onloadend: null,
        _listeners: [Object],
        onreadystatechange: null,
        _anonymous: undefined,
        readyState: 4,
        response: null,
        responseText: '',
        responseType: 'json',
        responseURL: '',
        status: 0,
        statusText: '',
        timeout: 0,
        upload: [Object],
        _method: 'GET',
        _url: [Object],
        _sync: false,
        _headers: [Object],
        _loweredHeaders: [Object],
        _mimeOverride: null,
        _request: null,
        _response: null,
        _responseParts: null,
        _responseHeaders: null,
        _aborting: null,
        _error: null,
        _loadedBytes: 0,
        _totalBytes: 0,
        _lengthComputable: false },
     currentTarget:
      XMLHttpRequest {
        onloadstart: null,
        onprogress: null,
        onabort: null,
        onerror: null,
        onload: null,
        ontimeout: null,
        onloadend: null,
        _listeners: [Object],
        onreadystatechange: null,
        _anonymous: undefined,
        readyState: 4,
        response: null,
        responseText: '',
        responseType: 'json',
        responseURL: '',
        status: 0,
        statusText: '',
        timeout: 0,
        upload: [Object],
        _method: 'GET',
        _url: [Object],
        _sync: false,
        _headers: [Object],
        _loweredHeaders: [Object],
        _mimeOverride: null,
        _request: null,
        _response: null,
        _responseParts: null,
        _responseHeaders: null,
        _aborting: null,
        _error: null,
        _loadedBytes: 0,
        _totalBytes: 0,
        _lengthComputable: false },
     lengthComputable: false,
     loaded: 0,
     total: 0 } }
```

The certificate of my server and the server I call are trusted and valid.
This is my server code:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import './global.imports';
import * as https from 'https';

enableProdMode();

const PORT = Number(process.env.PORT) || 4001;
const HOST_NAME = process.env.HOST;

const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

const app = express();

const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory} = require('main.server');

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const opts = {document: template, url: options.req.url};

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src');

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {req});
});

const privateKey = readFileSync(`${DIST_FOLDER}/server/config/ssl/key.pem`, 'utf8');
const certificate = readFileSync(`${DIST_FOLDER}/server/config/ssl/cert.pem`, 'utf8');

const credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

// your express configuration here

const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(PORT, HOST_NAME, () => {
  console.log(`listening to https://${HOST_NAME}:${PORT}`);
});
```

This is an evident problem with https, because if I put this env variable before nom start everything works, `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`, but it is not the solution because in this way I disable security.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you found any solution to it?

Comment: Any update? 2020 and still facing the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a very similar problem and struggled with it for a couple of hours. Applying the `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'` fix worked for me, but, as you say, the downside is that you compromise your app's security by exposing it to a man-in-the-middle attack.

Upon investigating further, I realized that the problem was not with Angular. I ran `https.get('<my-api-url>')` in a Node shell and I got: `Uncaught Error: unable to verify the first certificate`. Turns out, I had configured my API server with only the leaf certificate, not the full-chain certificate (leaf + CA bundle). Node apparently needs the full-chain certificate for verification, unlike browsers.

**Upon installing the *full-chain* certificate on my server, the problem went away without any changes to the app codebase.**